# Is there a way to use htaccess or other way you know to add a page as a url after the product slug on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

My client wants to create a specs page which comes after the product url

e.g [www.domain.com/product/%product%/specs](http://www.domain.com/product/%product%/specs)

I have create a custom php template for that page and it's ready. I am trying to find a way to make it load when someone goes to the product/specs page. Is there a way using htaccess or a plugin or a hook way to attach it to woocommerce's url?

Comment: I think the most proper way to do that, would be via https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: I will check on it. So it's possible.